# How to reload a javascript with a button on the website

Tags: javascript, html

I'm coding a little snake game in javascript so me and my friends can play it onlyine and copare our highscores. But when you go game over, you have to reload the site and can't just press a button like "Try Again" and it restarts the game/reloads the javascript

```
if(snakeX < box || snakeX > 17 * box || snakeY < 3*box || snakeY > 17*box || collision(newHead,snake)){
    clearInterval(game);
    dead.play();
}
```

that's the "game" interval `let game = setInterval(draw,100);`

Comment: Make a function that starts the game and is controlled by a button opposed to page load. Provide more relevant code if you want a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<button id="retry" style="display:none">Retry</button>
```

```
function Box() {...}

function Snake() {...}

function Game() {
    this._box = new Box()
    this._snake = new Snake()
    this._retry = document.getElementById('retry')

    this._retry.addEventListener('click', function () {
        this.start()
    })
}

Game.prototype.displayRetry = function () {
    this._retry.style = 'display:block'
}

Game.prototype.hideRetry = function () {
    this._retry.style = 'display:none'
}

Game.prototype.start = function () {
    this.hideRetry()
    this._snake.alive()
    this._interval = setInterval(function () { this.draw() }, 100)
}

Game.prototype.check = function () {
    var bounds = this._box.bounds
    var position = this._snake.position

    return position.x < bounds.xMin || position.x > bounds.xMax || position.y < bounds.yMin || position.y > bounds.yMax || this._snake.hasCollidedWithSelf()
}

Game.prototype.draw = function () {
   // ...

   if (this.check()) {
       this.end()
   }
}

Game.prototype.end = function () {
    this._snake.dead()
    this.displayRetry()
}
```